# Handling background data Transfer on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to windows phone OS development and I want to implement a background data transfer on windows phone 8.1 and I want to do it even after app is running in background. On windows 8 there is an Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer API but what about windows phone OS. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [Transferring data in the background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh452975(v=win.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer is in fact supported on windows phone 8.1, here is the sample code : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61

But if you want to maintain windows phone 8 support you can use BackgroundTransferService instead. Sample code for it can be found here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202959(v=vs.105).aspx